# Permission denied when trying to anonymously clone a github repository

Tags: git, github

As an anonymous user (no public key stored at github) I try to clone a public repository through the `git@...` URL. But it fails:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf.git
Cloning into 'phpwkhtmltopdf'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So does this mean, github does not allow anonymous access through the SSH protocol? If so, is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I just found out that there's another button at github that says "Git Read-only". It gives a similar but slightly different URL that works:

```
git://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf.git
```

EDIT: As @damick pointed out below the button seems to be gone now. But you can still manually change the original URL to match the pattern shown here.

Comment: i don't see that button anywhere anymore, but i was able to edit my clone link like yours and it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

That is most likely because it was trying to use SSH credentials, and with https its not.
Therefore when you used

```
git clone git://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf.git
```

it worked. :D

Comment: This is a reply to another answer and doesn't contain the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use `git clone https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf.git`