# GoodData: JavaScript SDK setup - repo cloning error

Tags: javascript, git, gooddata

Trying to follow the 'Getting Started' for the GoodDataJS here: http://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-js/getting-started/

When trying to clone repo it fails with the error:

"Cloning into 'gooddata-js'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Comment: You might want to report it to the gooddata people.  Use this instead:  `git clone https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-js.git`

Comment: We're sorry for this, I've fixed that already.

Answer (score 1):

That happens if you never registered a public/private ssh key to your account.
See "[GitHub - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2643584/6309)" and "[Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)".

In that case, as commented, only https would work.

```
git clone https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-js.git
```

ssh and https protocols allows for user authentication.

True anonymous cloning *could* be supported (as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16187849/6309)) with:

```
git clone git://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-js.git
```

But that supposed your workstation allows port 9418 (used by git protocol) for outgoing connection.