# git error while deploying through chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, ssh, chef-infra

i am trying to deploy rails app through chef code.  recipe contains code

```rb
deploy_revision "testapp" do    
  repo "REPO_URL"    
  ssh_wrapper "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/chef_ssh_deploy_wrapper.sh"    
  environment({    
    "RAILS_ENV" => "staging"    
  })    
  deploy_to "/home/ubuntu/testapp"    
  branch "master"    
  user "ubuntu"    
  group "ubuntu"    
  scm_provider Chef::Provider::Git    
end
```

and sshwrapper file contains

```
exec ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no github.com -i "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa" "$@"
```

when i ran bootstrap

im getting error as follows

> STDERR: Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>   192.168.1.32 Permission denied (publickey).
>   192.168.1.32 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   192.168.1.32 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   192.168.1.32 and the repository exists.
>   192.168.1.32 ---- End output of git ls-remote "REPO_URL"     master* ----

so , unable to figure it out the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you registered an ssh key to your GitHub account, as I just explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24277691/6309?

Comment: yes, i registered . i can clone repo on host machine manually.

Comment: Does chef has access to the same key, in its HOME/.ssh?

Comment: yes , it is all readable. added 644 permission for config file.

Comment: So it accesses the same HOME as your account?

Comment: yes . it access the same . it even clone the id_rsa files,config files in ,ssh directory from template.

Comment: can you clone the repo as `ubuntu` user using the sshwrapper file?

Comment: got the issue. problem with the wrapper file. thanks StephenKing for the hint. extra string github.com in wrapper file caused the problem. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: @ManjunathBavihal its probably worth adding an answer for the question which explains that the extra github.com bit in the sshwrapper was wrong.